# Illegal member initialization when base class shares field names with derived class

Tags: c++

I have a hierarchy of `Shape->`,`Triangle->` and `Triforce` who all have a private string member sName.

```
`Shape::Shape(string name) : sName(name){}`
```

In the Triforce class (inherits from Triangle) I can use this construcotr:

```
Triforce::Triforce(string name) : Triangle(name){}
```

but this one
`Triforce::Triforce(string name) : Shape(name){}`
gives the error: `illegal member initialization 'Shape' is not a base or member.
How does this work?  Since they're all in the same hierarchy why does calling the parent compiler but not the base class?

Answer (score 1):

Every `Triangle` constructor must - explicitly or implicitly - invoke one of the `Shape` constructors, so in `Triforce` it's reasonable to pick which `Triangle` instructor to invoke and let it coordinate the `Shape` construction, but not reasonable to interfere with `Shape` construction as you're trying to do - how's the `Triangle` constructor supposed to know about having had its base `Shape` object already constructed?  You should keep a `Triforce::Triforce(const std::string& name) : Triangle(name) { }` constructor and remove the one attempting to call the `Shape` constructor.

Comment: I didn't think about it like you mentioned, it's gotta be a triangle before it can be a triforce.

Comment: Tangentially, if all three of these classes have the same private variable is it better to pass that in a base constructor?

Comment: *"is it better to pass that in a base constructor?"*  I'm not sure I understand your question.  The code in your question has the base class constructor being passed a value for the private variable - that's all good.  I don't see any reason to change from what you've done other than to remove the `Triforce` constructor that's trying to initialise `Shape` directly.

Comment: All three classes have the same string variable, so it's like a protected variable.  They're supposed to be "bad" according to Clean Code.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: it's *unlike* a protected variable in that the management of that variable is still encapsulated in the base class, so - for example - the base class could choose to do something like convert it to uppercase, knowing derived classes couldn't set it later, breaking the uppercase *invariant*/expectation.  That's all good.  If you've read something that you think applies here and categorises it as "bad", please provide a link so I can consider the advice....